# Javascript skipping for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, command-line-interface, inquirer

I am writing a CLI application using JS and `inquirer`. From the following code, I expect to get some console.log() from both of the for loops. However, there is no console.log even if `checkChoices` and `answers` both have values inside of them.

**JS**

```
view(){
        let checkChoices = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++){
            checkChoices.push(this.list[i].text);
        }

        let viewList = [
            {
                type: 'checkbox',
                name: 'command',
                message: 'Your Checklist',
                choices: checkChoices
            }
        ]

        console.log(checkChoices.length);
        inquirer.prompt(viewList).then((answers) => {
            for(let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){
                let answer = answers[i];
                console.log("answer", answer)
                for(let j = 0; j < checkChoices.length; j++){
                    console.log("choice", checkChoices[j])
                    if(answer == checkChoices[j]){
                        this.list[j].complete = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log(this.list);
            // this.ask();
        })
    }
  };
```

Comment: Put a console log immediately before your first `for` and verify the success part of the `then` is even happening

Comment: @Taplar I put the console.log before the first for loop, and it prints out perfectly fine.

Comment: Alright so if you `console.log(answers)` what does it look like?

Comment: @Taplar looks like this: { command: [ 'hello' ] }

Comment: Alright, so that's an object.  Objects don't have a length.  You want to use `answers.command` for the array

Comment: @Taplar Thanks! You can submit that as an answer, and I'll verify it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the comments, it was discovered that `answers` was an object, rather than an array.  Objects do not, inheriently, have a `length` property.

As the object had a single property of `command` with a value of an array, the assumption is that the logic should loop over `answers.command`, rather than trying to loop on the answers object.